# CSS3 button with two colours

Tags: html, css, button

I wanted to ask what is the best way to create such button with css:

[image]

I was trying to create such button with divs using float left and right, but when i zoom in and out right side of the button drops down. Is there a better way to achieve this?

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/asmKj/308/)

```
<div style="width:270px">
    <div class="button">
        <div>
            <div>text</div>
            <div>text</div>
        </div>
        <div><div></div></div>
    </div>
</div>

.button {
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.button > div:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #008f70;
    background-color: #00b48c;
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 165px;
}

.button > div:first-child > div:first-child {
    color: #b8e3d6;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

.button > div:first-child > div:last-child {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20pt;
}

.button > div:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 9px;
    background-color: #008f70;
    width: 64px;
    height: 81px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `select` element?

Comment: or [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-split)?

Comment: Bootstrap is not an option in my project

Comment: @chipChocolate.py last i checked, long time ago, it was not possible to remove the built in drop-down arrow from the `select` tag. Unless you mimic the select tag behavior, and just added a css img rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All it takes:

```css
button.styled{
  color:#fff;
  background:#00B48C;     /* CHANGE ONLY THIS ONE AND SEE IT HAPPEN ;) */
  padding:10px 45px 10px 15px;
  border-radius:4px;
  /* Do not edit below */
  border:0;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
button.styled:after{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding:11px;
  content:'\25be'; /* \25bc \25be */
  /* Do not edit below */
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<button class="styled">Hello World</button>
```

For more UTF-8 characters see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25986009/383904

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the duplicate `div` with `text` and add top and bottom `padding` to the other `div` with `text`.

You can use Font Awesome to get the caret sign in the dropdown.

```css
.button {
  height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.button > div:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #008f70;
  background-color: #00b48c;
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
  padding: 22px 15px 26px 15px; /* add top and bottom border */
  width: 165px;
}

.button > div:first-child > div:first-child {
  color: #b8e3d6;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

.button > div:first-child > div:last-child {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

.button > div:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 9px;
  background-color: #008f70;
  width: 64px;
  height: 81px;
  position: relative;
}

i{
  margin-left: 45%;
  margin-top: 45%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div style="width:270px">
  <div class="button">
    <div>
      <div>text</div>
    </div>
    <div><div><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></div></div> <!-- add the caret -->
  </div>
</div>
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asmKj/309/)

[Source](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/caret-down/)

Comment: caret sign is not the problem. Try zoom in or zoom out the jsfiddle. You will see there the problem is. Btw thanks for suggestion

Comment: @kuldarim Are you talking about the gap in between the 2 elements that we see on zoom in? By the way, I updated my answer and refined the code.

Comment: @kuldarim I was not able to reproduce that using the code in my answer. Could you please check?

Answer (score 1):

you can use only one element with `pseudo` elements `:before` and `:after`

```css
button {
  border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #008f70;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #00b48c;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 165px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}
button:before {
  content: '\25BE';
  position: absolute;
  right: -32px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  top: 50%;
  color: white;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
}
button:after {
  content: '';
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 9px;
  background-color: #008f70;
  width: 54px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: -1px
}
button:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<button>test</button>
```

Comment: Maybe you know why cursor pointer is no visible in firefox for the seccond part of the button? To be more specific it is not visible in :after button part. In chrome everything is OK. You can find an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/e0p161k6/3/