# display alertbox with image

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display javascript alertbox with  I want to display this dialog with image init.Now I get alertbox as show in image
[image]
 I want to include delete1.png image before try again.

```
       <SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
       window.alert('Try again');
       </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: You cannot use an image but you can use a nice UTF-8 icon symbol (if supported by browser fonts)

Comment: Sure: http://jsbin.com/lujeqe/1/ >> Find them here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25986009/383904

Comment: Is it possible to display image

Comment: If it were possible I would not suggest you to use UTF-8. You should go for creating a modal popup. All it takes are few lines of JS and a DIV element..

Answer (score 2):

You can't display an image in Javascript alert box, it can only show text. You may implement `modal` with any of the available ui libraries like Bootstrap/jQuery/ jQuery-UI, etc.

You can also refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992142/html-modal-popup) for some inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Adding image to alert() is not possible. Instead you can try this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("<img src='img.jpg'> This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 200px wide and 100px tall!");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build an alert box on your own using jQuery and
pulling the alert-box text from an element's data-* attribute:

```js
var $alertCov  = $("#alert-cover");
var $alertCont = $("#alert-content");
var $alertOK   = $("#alert > button");

$("[data-alert]").on("click", function(){
  $alertCont.html( $(this).data("alert") );
  $alertCov.stop().fadeIn(300);
});
$alertOK.click(function(){
  $alertCov.fadeOut(300);
});
```

```css
#alert-cover{
  display:none;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  position:fixed;
  left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
#alert{
  position:fixed;
  z-index:99999;
  background:#fafafa;
  max-width:280px;
  padding:10px 15px 15px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:20px auto;
  box-shadow:0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#alert > button{
  background:#ddd;
  border:0;
  padding:7px 15px;
  cursor:pointer;
  border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="alert-cover">
  <div id="alert">
    <div id="alert-content">
      Filled by data-* attribute
    </div>
    <button>OK</button>
  </div>
</div>
  
  
<a href="javascript:;" data-alert="
    <h2>Hello</h2>                                     
    <p><img src='//placehold.it/30x30/f0f'> World</p>
    "> Click me! </a>
  
<button data-alert="<p>Are you sure?</p>">click me!</button>
```