# Gallery for my website

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery, image-gallery

Sorry for my not so perfect english in advance.

I've been making a site for my music band as a school project and i've done pretty much everything, but i don't get it **how to take a finished gallery and add my photos and stuff**?

(My teacher told me that i don't need to make gallery if i don't know how and that i can find a finished one on web). I was looking for finished galleries but i couldn't get to put them in my code, i also looked for tutorials, but after all, none of the galleries couldn't fulfill what i needed and those whom i tried to put in my website couldn't work. So i want a gallery to be like this:

- a line (slider) of thumbnails of photos on whom i can click
- and when i click on them they zoom into bigger resolution (like a bit
  slow fade in)
- everything behind the image becomes darker and also
- the left and right arrows which can be used with mouse click and
- arrow buttons on keyboard as previous and next and
- when i click anywhere beside the image it fades out (it can just fade out, if possible (i like that effect more), without changing resolution, or
  it can just zoom out).

I would learn if i could, because deadline is
   tomorrow, so please if anyone can help me, i'm sure that there're
   finished galleries like the one i want, but i just couldn't find
   one... and ofcourse if you could explain to me how to add my images
   and everything. Sorry again for my english...

Comment: Could you post some code from your website here you tried to integrate a gallery but it didn't work?

Comment: I've erased everything :/ i got really mad and just erased it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/gudora/5/edit?html,output)***

Put this inside a `gallery.html` document

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Darkbox by Roko C. Buljan</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      *{margin:0;}
      html,body{height:100%;}
      /* *********************** */
      /* DARKBOX STYLES */
      img[data-darkbox]{
        height:130px;
      }
      #darkbox{
        position:fixed;
        z-index:9999;
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) no-repeat none 50% / contain;
        box-shadow:0 0 0 3000px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        opacity:0; visibility:hidden;
      }
      #darkbox.on{ 
        opacity:1; visibility:visible;
        height:90% !important; width:90% !important;
        left:5% !important; top:5% !important;
      }
      #darkbox:after{
        position:absolute;
        right:0; top:0;
        font-size:2em;
        content:"\2A2F";
        color:#fff;
        cursor:pointer;
      }
      /*prev next buttons*/
      #prev,
      #next{
        cursor:pointer;
        user-select:none;
        -webkit-user-select:none;
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        margin-top:-25px;
        height:50px;
        width:50px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
      }
      #prev:hover,
      #next:hover{
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
      }
      #prev{left: -2px;}
      #next{right: -2px;} 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- HERE GOES YOUR DOCUMENT HTML -->

    <h1>Darkbox</h1>
    <p>You can also use arrow keys and ESC to close Darkbox</p>

    <img data-darkbox src="http://placehold.it/400x300/8ac?text=a">
    <img data-darkbox src="http://placehold.it/800x600/ca7?text=b">
    <img data-darkbox src="http://placehold.it/600x900/88c?text=c">
    <img data-darkbox src="http://placehold.it/900x500/a88?text=d">
    <img data-darkbox src="http://placehold.it/860x550/c8c?text=e">

    <!-- end/HERE GOES YOUR DOCUMENT HTML -->



    <!-- KEEP SCRIPTS BEFORE THE CLOSING /BODY TAG -->
    <script>
      // Darkbox // by Roko C.B.
      var $images = $('img[data-darkbox]');
      var n = $images.length;
      var c = 0; // counter
      var $prevNext = $("<div id='prev'/><div id='next'/>").on("click", function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        var isNext = this.id==="next";
        c = (isNext ? c++ : --c) < 0  ? n-1 : c%n;
        $images.eq( c ).click();
      });
      var $darkbox = $("<div/>",{
        id: "darkbox",
        html: $prevNext
      }).on("click", function(){
        $(this).removeClass("on");
      }).appendTo("body");

      $images.css({cursor:"pointer"}).on("click",function(){
        var o=this.getBoundingClientRect();
        c = $images.index( this );
        $darkbox.css({
          transition: "0s",
          backgroundImage: "url("+this.src+")",
          left: o.left,
          top: o.top,
          height: this.height,
          width: this.width
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
          $darkbox.css({transition:"0.8s"}).addClass("on"); 
        },5);
      });

      $(document).on("keyup", function(e){
        var k = e.which;
        if(k==27) /*ESC */  $("#darkbox").click(); // close Darkbox
        if(k==37) /*LEFT*/  $("#prev").click();
        if(k==39) /*RIGHT*/ $("#next").click();
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Roko, you nailed it. Depending on the level of OP's familiarity with Javascript and jQuery, you may want to add in a link to jQuery for him. At the very least hosted on a CDN.

Comment: <body>
 <div class=divmain>
 <h1>Gallery</h1>
 <hr>
  
 </div>
</body>

here is a div where gallery should be, i tried but it didn't work very well. There are other things on website and css offcourse, but this is that part where gallery should be (it should start under <hr> tag)

Comment: @SamuelLJackson (BTW I like your movies hhh ;) I know, I've put the jQuery already but cause of wrong indentation it was eaten by SO's editor in the answer preview. Fixed.
Predrag, Inside jsBin find the download link.

Comment: @Predrag open the jsBin link and see where I've put my images, OK, you don't need to put them inside BODY, you put them after your `<hr>` tag. Seems obvious... since you need to put them somewhere :) Anyway, click download inside jsBin, open that .html file and have fun.

Comment: It works visually, but it doesn't react when i click on it, sorry for slow answering, my computer is reeeeally slow :( yes, if you could do it i would be very very grateful

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for bothering

Comment: Also, it works perfectly now :D i tried an online editor and it worked, i just don't know why it didn't worked via browser only (http://www.onlinehtmleditor.net i went here and it worked) just those prev next buttons and that's it. Hvala puno ;)

Comment: @Predrag - Edited my answer with the arrows , buttons and also ESC key functionality. Happy coding. If you don't understand parts of my code feel free to ask. ( *Nema na čemu! :)* )

Comment: Thank you man again very very very much, everything works fine now :D i just don't know how to change image for that "X" button in top right when i click on image, just tell me that and that's it :D (hvala ti još jednom nenormalno mnogo, spasio si me xD)

Comment: @Predrag The "X" is simply a `&times;` x character used with hex for CSS as `\2a2f` See inside CSS for `#darkbox:after` you'll see this line: `content:"\2A2F";`. you can remove that line and instead style your `:after` pseudo element using `width:40px; height:40px; background: url(closePopup.png);` or any other image you want.

Comment: @Predrag if you want another character, I've created a UTF-8 characters generator you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985680/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-all-special-html-characters/25986009#25986009

Comment: Yes, now i know everything i need, thank you again xD